# Trying to Listen for GET on Port 80

Tags: python, tcp, packet, tcpdump

I want to be able to read the URL GET requests coming to my server, ex: "www.JohnAlexINL.com/ping" or "http://johnalexinl.com/", et cetera.

I've tried using TCPDump, but it gives me a bunch of garbled nonsense that I can't figure out how to translate back into the original request (I can track the sources and read the packets, but I can't get them back into a URL). I've also tried just listening on my TCP/UDP/HTTP ports, but that causes compatibility issues with Apache, effectively shutting my website down

I tried this first

`sudo tcpdump -vv -x -i lo 'port 80'`
and without 'port 80' later 

`sudo tcpdump -vv -x -i lo`

I tried a few other configurations and having it save to a file and sifting through it, but I was doing that in IDLE, so I don't remember anymore exactly how I typed it all out. Sorry for that

I was hoping I would see the TCP "Handshake", a GET request, and some packets in response that have the actual data in them.

I got something somewhat similar, but not that I can actually use, since it only says what data has been moved -- not the request that warranted the response.

An excerpt:

```
19:45:25.293910 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4474, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 103)
    localhost.domain > localhost.36156: [bad udp cksum 0xfe9a -> 0xee1b!] 30218 q: PTR? 53.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/1 53.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. PTR localhost. ar: . OPT UDPsize=65494 (75)
    0x0000:  4500 0067 117a 4000 4011 2ad6 7f00 0035
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0035 8d3c 0053 fe9a 760a 8180
    0x0020:  0001 0001 0000 0001 0235 3301 3001 3003
    0x0030:  3132 3707 696e 2d61 6464 7204 6172 7061
    0x0040:  0000 0c00 01c0 0c00 0c00 0100 0000 0000
    0x0050:  0b09 6c6f 6361 6c68 6f73 7400 0000 29ff
    0x0060:  d600 0000 0000 00
```

Comment: Tell us what you’re trying to achieve. Are you setting up a web server? Do you want to analyze the low-level network traffic? Start by stating the problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: The excerpt you posted is a DNS request on UDP, not part of the TCP connection.

Comment: Don't quote the filter. `tcpdump -vv -x -i lo port 80`

Comment: @Barmar -- Tried again without the filter, didn't make any difference; same output in the terminal. I only posted that excerpt to show that I'm only getting sources, destinations, and the packets. I only care about the URL the user initially typed in, and I'm getting pretty much everything besides that. Didn't want to put a dump on here. The TCP and UPD verbose look about the same ``` localhost.58340 > localhost.http: Flags [S], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x1720), seq 1056236181, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 7440351 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0 ``` for example

Comment: @ChrisJohnson -- I'm trying to monitor the GET requests that come to my website so that I can use Python scripts to automatically make updates to my database. Ex, I want to be able to pass a request like "http://johnalexinl.com/_rep11xupdate", and then have my Python script generate a text file that has a list of the files that would need updating after Version 11 of the REP program for my P.O.S systems

Comment: I would watch apache logs instead of sitting on network layer. Just read apache logs as they go, when a new line arrives trigger the update that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using entirely the wrong toolset. Choose a simple web framework like web.py and follow the examples.

Comment: I didn't know that service existed, and it's printing out the GET requests, as just a default setting! Big thanks, Chris. Should be a lot easier to make everything work using web.py

Comment: Good luck. In python, practically anything you can imagine already exists as a library. Always best to spend a few minutes searching for an off-the-shelf solution.